# How to find the $60$th percentile of pdf?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, percentile

The pdf of $x$ is $f(x) = .1$ with the interval $3 < x < 13 $

This problem requires me to find the $60$th percentile. I assume that I need to solve for the interval from $3$ to $13$ of this function first, but I am not sure what I should do next. Can someone please explain what I need to do? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find such a number $p$ that $\mathbb{P}[x \le p] = 0.6$. Note that $\mathbb{P}[X \le 3] = 0$ and $\mathbb{P}[X \le 13] = 1$ and since the probability density does not depend on location, the probability function will grow linearly in-between these two.

Comment: Oh, so it is 9?

Comment: @Mary correct indeed